# Completion, set theoretic isomorphism or topological isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, ring-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

> A ring $R$ is complete with respect to an ideal $I$ if the natural map
> $R\rightarrow\varprojlim_{n\geq 1}R/I^n$ is an isomorphism. This is
> the same as asking that $R$ is complete (in the sense that every
> Cauchy sequence converges) with respect to the $I$-adic topology. '

cited from [A complete ring with respect to an ideal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494832/a-complete-ring-with-respect-to-an-ideal)

In such a statement, 'isomorphism' is set theoretic bijection?
Or topological isomorphism? I want to clarify that. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Isomorphism means an isomorphism of rings but since the natural map is a homomorphism of rings by construction, it suffices that it be a set-theoretic bijection. The $I$-adic topology on $R$ is more or less by definition the topology that makes this map a homeomorphism, if the RHS is given the limit topology (that is, if we take the limit in topological rings).